# ssh x11 forwarding drag-and-drop

Tags: ssh, x11, xforwarding

Is it possible to drag-n-drop into x11 forwarded application?
For instance, I'm forwarding skype and I'd like to send a file by dropping it into message box. Yes, I know I can work it around. This question is not skype-specific.

Comment: this really sounds application specific, can you give more details on why you think it is not?

Comment: @son_of_fire We can use drag-n-drop not only in skype but in browsers, file-manages etc.

Comment: what is your window manager? OS etc...

Comment: Client is FreeBSD running xfwm, host is ArchLinux with plain old X window manager.

Comment: I think you need to [forward D-Bus](http://machine-cycle.blogspot.fr/2010/12/ssh-and-dbus-sessions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Draging and dropping a file to an application will depend on how the application handles the drop. But in any case, if the file that you're dropping does not exist on the Machine that is x-forwarding to your machine, the drop will fail.
But, for example, if you're dropping a file that is on a network share AND that machine has the exactly same share, it will work.
When you drop a file, normally the drop is a full path to the file, nothing else.
If both machines can see the path, it will work, if not, fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the remote file manager over SSH forwarding. Then, drag and drop from the remote file manager window to the Skype window will work. I just tested it, although with Zotero instead of Skype.